# Why was Bing Bong collecting memories?

Tags: character, inside-out

In Bing Bong's first appearance in *Inside Out*, he is seen taking memories straight off the long term memory shelf. Later, his bag has dozens if not a few hundred memories in it. Why was Bing Bong collecting these memories?

Comment: Just a speculation: maybe they were memory involving him. He wanted to remember the good times when he was so important in the life of Riley.

Comment: It might be a symbol for our childhood trying to grasp and not forget some of its memories. He's the part of Riley's mind that doesn't want to let go of her childhood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is never explained in the movie. However, his appearance and his actions seem to me like they were [intended by the movie's creators to make him seem like a villain](https://ohmy.disney.com/insider/2015/06/24/why-bing-bong-is-the-greatest-disney-pixar-character-ever/):

> Let’s go back to Bing Bong’s introduction: he’s first spotted by Joy
>   (Amy Poehler) and Sadness (Phyllis Smith) in long-term memory. **This is
>   the area of Riley’s mind that is supposed to be off-limits**, populated
>   only by blobby mind workers that perform maintenance and provide
>   valuable upkeep and categorization. But this is where Bing Bong has
>   found himself—**he’s stealing Riley’s memories, hoarding his favorites
>   in a “make believe” bag** that also includes (in no particular order) a
>   shoe, a kitchen sink, and a live cat. He’s dressed shabbily, like a
>   hobo in an old Hollywood movie: torn, fingerless gloves and patches on
>   the elbow of his jackets. Given his working knowledge of the Train of
>   Thought, you can tell he’s been riding the rails. All he’s missing is
>   a polka-dotted bindle. (**We saw the first hour of Inside Out at a press
>   event earlier this year and were convinced, for many weeks, that Bing
>   Bong was going to turn out to be the film’s villain; the filmmakers
>   admitted to us that this was purposeful and a way to keep the audience
>   on their toes.**)

Comment: Huh, watching the movie, I never once thought that he would turn out to be the villain. Regardless, is there an in-universe reason in the final version that explains his behavior? Or is it purely speculative?